# how to get specific word out of sentence in UIAutomation?

Tags: ios, instruments, ios-ui-automation

If i need to check whether some specific word is present in some sentence, then what syntax/code i should use in javascript for UIAutomation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use function indexOf():

Search a string for "welcome":

```
 var str="Hello world, welcome to the universe.";
 var n=str.indexOf("welcome");
```

The result of **n** will be:

13

This method returns -1 if the value to search is not present.